# What does this means IE GIVES error on following code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 onStepValidate(validated, model) {       
        if (validated) {
            this.finalModel = {...this.finalModel, ...model};
        }
    },
```

Above code gives folowing error in IE /Edge

SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Expected identifier, string or number

Comment: IE doesn't support spread syntax. Are you transpiling this through babel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have IE to test in right this moment, but It's probably the object syntax you're using. Rather than `{...this.finalModel, ...model}`, `this.finalModel = Object.assign({}, this.finalModel, model)` will work in Edge, and you could provide an `Object.assign` polyfill for IE. Or you could make sure your config is set to compile down for IE and Edge. If you're using `vue-cli`, check the [browser compatibility page](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist) for information on configuring browser support.